# What is the order for putting on a tallis katan in the morning?

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, tallit-katan

I heard that upon waking up, even before washing al netilas yadayim, you put on your tallis katan, then wash your hands, use the bathroom, wash hands again and then make an al netilas yadayim....and then a bracho on the tallis katan (this is all in order not to walk more than 4 amos without wearing tzizis). Is this correct? I was learning the Mishna berurah (8:2) that says that you should only make the bracho on a tallis katan BEFORE you are about to put it on, which would be much later until after using the bathroom. What should be done? - 1) put the tallis katan on before netilas yadayim or 2) after you've used the bathroom and washed your hands and are able to say the bracho do you then put it on?

Comment: I dont think you put your clothes on before you wash negel vasser.

Comment: This question makes many assumptions, which make it somewhat difficult to answer accurately. I think those assumptions should be delineated. For example, there are those who say one should not make a berakhah on a Tallit Qatan at all if one will be donning a Tallit Gadol shortly thereafter.

Comment: "What should be done?" A lot of people think you should wear it at night...